# Как поставить значение по умолчанию в модели?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

У модели `Post` есть связь `has_many :through` с моделью `Category`.

Нужно сделать так, чтобы если вдруг при каком-либо сценарии у поста не оказалось категории, то ему автоматически добавится указанная.

Пробовал в модели `Category` добавить `around_destroy`, где после удаления идет проверка на наличие категорий в посте и, если нет, то добавляем нужную.

Этот вариант работает, но есть проблема, которая возникает при `@post.destroy!`.

Как реализовать поставленную задачу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как отправной вариант, добавьте в модель `Post`, валидацию на присутствие хотя бы одной категории:

```
has_many :categories, through: :categoriable, dependent: :destroy
validates :categories, length: { minimum: 1}
```

Этим можно сократить количество случаев, когда у вас отсутствует категория. В промежуточной модели `Сategoriable` (не уверен, что она у вас так называется), добавьте параметр `touch`, который будет дергать `Post` при удалении связи.

```
belongs_to :categoriable, touch: true
```

Тогда в принципе можно исключить ситуацию, когда у вас `Post` остается без категории. Можно добавить `after_save` колбэк, который будет следить, не получилось ли так, что у поста осталось ноль категорий и назначать категорию по умолчанию. Однако руками или `destroy!` можно наделать дел все-равно... т.е. это вопрос времени, когда у вас появятся посты без категорий.

Самый лучший вариант, это вообще исключить возможность удаления категорий, у которых есть хотя бы один пост. В самом деле, что значит удалить категорию у поста, у которого единственная категория? Не лучше ли вместо удаления категории предусмотреть процедуру слияния, когда вы можете передать посты сливаемой категории какой-то другой? Предусмотреть отдельную форму и select-выбор в какую категорию вы предаете потенциальные посты-сироты?